# .dylib mobile substrate tweaks not working

Tags: iphone, ios5, jailbreak, tweak, cydia-substrate

I was learning about making mobile substrate tweak when i came across a tutorial with a source codes in it. To further understand it, i decided to test it out

The codes:

```
  %hook SBApplicationIcon
  -(void)launch
  {
  NSString *appName = [self displayName];
  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app %@ has been launched, lol", appName, nil];
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:appName message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
  %orig;
  }
  %end
```

I used theos on my IOS phone and made a tweak and paste this code into the "tweak.xm"
I went to "makefile" and added

```
test_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit
```

if u ever wonder what is in my test.plist, here is it

```
com.apple.springboard
```

Next i went to mobile terminal and did this

```
su
alpine
cd test
make
```

Then u copied the .dylib and the "test.plist" file that theos made and pasted it in /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries

After that i respring my device and tried launching an app, but nothing happened. Everything launched normally. Please help me here

Answer (score 1):

After googling for a long time, i finally made it to work

I went to mobile terminal... and login. After that i did this

```
installsdk3
```

Then i went to my Makefile and changed it to this

```
SDKVERSION = 3

include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = test
test_FILES = Tweak.xm
test_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit Foundation

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

And i remade the tweak again and it worked!